# Installing Oracle SQL*Loader SQLLDR on RHEL7 from Instant Client

Tags: linux, oracle, rhel7

I have been assigned a task to create a environment setup which a piece of java program uses. This piece of java program uses sqlldr to bulk upload the data into database.

Now the client's machine already has Oracle InstantClient 18.5 version configured. To the existing config I have to add sqlldr using the Tools Package (RPM) provided by Oracle [oracle-instantclient18.5-tools-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm](https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/185000/oracle-instantclient18.5-tools-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm). Correct? There is a .zip file available as well on the website.

Now I do not know how to do that. I have normally installed software using yum or apt-get. Can anyone please help me.

Here is the existing config which could be of concern, I do not wanna disturb the other setups apart from what I wanna add to it.

```
ORACLE_HOME= /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/
ORACLE_BASE= /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/lib/:/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5/:
```

Questions:

1. Now do I need to download this .rpm file onto the server?
2. If download then download in /tmp folder, then next? Do I need to install anything else? If yes how can I verify if my current setup already do not have that?
3. Once installed any post configurations need to be done specially for sqlldr to run?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Is Oracle database *server* software installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have Instant Client from ZIP files. (If it was instead from RPMs, you would have the files in `/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/...`).

So simply unzip the Tools ZIP file so its contents are in your `/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_5` directory, and make sure this directory is in your PATH.

Because you are using Instant Client you should unset ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_BASE.  The former can cause problems if it is set with Instant Client.

In general, follow the Instant Client installation instructions at the foot of the [download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html).

Also look at using Instant Client 19, which is a Long Term Support version and will connect to the same databases as Instant Client 18.  Notice that there are no new Instant Client 18 "Release Updates" being released (though you could build them yourself, if needed).